# Some packages were not found?

Tags: r

When I opened my R.It showed some warning messages,meaning I lost some packages,just like

```
Warning message:
package "methods" in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
During startup - Warning messages:
1: package ‘datasets’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
2: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
3: package ‘grDevices’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
4: package ‘graphics’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
5: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
6: package ‘methods’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

Then I couldn't use some basic functions,and I re-installed R twice,it was still not work.Anyone know how to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problems-with-Rterm-2-13-0-but-not-RGui-td3490034.html) on R help, your R path might be corrupted:

> *"Now I've tracked down the problem a bit, and the problem appears to be
>   connected to which folder R is called from."* by Stefan McKinnon Edwards

You can either adapt your PATH variable or try to reinstall R in **another** folder and start it from there. This should fix the problem.

Comment: That link is dead.